# Passing a Control Type to a procedure

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, casting, typeof

I'm trying to make a generic procedure to change the visible property of "X" control object to "False/True" just by calling this procedure with the arguments you can see:

```
    ' Desired usage:
    ' Disable_Controls(CheckBox, Me.Panel1.Controls, False)

    Public Sub Disable_Controls(ByVal ControlType As Control, _
                                ByVal Container As ControlCollection, _
                                ByVal Visible As Boolean)

        For Each Control As Control In Container
            ' If TypeOf Control Is CheckBox then...
            If TypeOf Control Is Control Then
                Control.Visible = Visible
            End If
        Next

    End Sub
```

The problem is I can't pass the control name ("Checkbox") like I'm trying to do it,
I've tried some things using "CType(Control, CheckBox)" but did not work.

How I can do that?

Comment: Why is `ControlType` of type `Control` and not of, say `Type`?  `typeof control` will always return true because you're `As`'ing it as `Control` above.  I'm not sure what the goal is.  Is it to search `ControlCollection` and find all controls of a certain type (`Checkbox` for example) and disable them?

Comment: @Eli Gassert yes that's the goal, but I wanted to make it generic to work with all type of controls (Checkbox, Button, etc...) just by calling the sub with the "ControlName" parameter as the first param.

Comment: @Eli Gasser asking to your first question, ControlType is "Control" and not "Type" 'cause I don't know the good way to do this, now I've changed it to "Type" and I'm still trying things. thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Sub Disable_Controls(Of T As Control)(ByVal Container As Control, _
                            ByVal Visible As Boolean)
    For Each ctrl As T In Container.Controls.OfType(Of T)()
        ctrl.Visible = Visible
    Next
End Sub
```

Call it like this:

```
Disable_Controls(Of Checkbox)(MyGroupbox, False)
```

Comment: does `Container.OfType` filter all its contents to just the ones of that type, or does it try to cast all elements of that container to that type?  If the former (filters) then nice and elegant answer!

Comment: Thankyou, but the sub is throwing an exception at the "For" Line (T): T is a type and cannot be used as an expression, that's the same error I always have trying to passing/casting the first argument.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn Waiting for a update to resolve the (T) exception in your answer, thanks!

Comment: `.OfType()` does filter vs cast everything. It will keep child controls if you pass a parent type. The exception is because I was missing a set of parentheses and the `Of` keyword. It should work now.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn Does not work: Error 1 Type parameters cannot be used as qualifiers.   at " T.Visible = Visible" line

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn This is not working: " Disable_Controls(Of Button)(Me.Panel1.Controls, False)" Can't convert object type 'ControlCollection' to type 'ControlCollection', I don't know why, are the same type!. Also I can't use your example "Disable_Controls(Of Checkbox)(MyGroupbox.Controls, False)" in groupboxes don't work, only works in "me.controls", I've tried to change "ByVal Container As Object" but then returns other exception.

Comment: Hmmm... one more round. Note that the "how to use it" part changed also